# slidetoShow, slidetoScroll set to 0 produces chrome running out of memory

Tags: jquery

I have implemented slick slider in magento project. In my project, all the images I have displayed dynamically. There are two sliders. One for thumbnail image slider and other one for small thumbnail image slider.
Now I don't want to scroll images in second small thumbnail image slider. for that I have set slideToShow and slideToScroll set to 0.
Whenever I access that product page in localhost, it gives Chrome running out of memory. why this is happening?

When I set above values to 1, project running successfully.

```
    <?php $thumbnails = $this->getGalleryImages(); ?>
    <?php if (count($thumbnails) > 0): ?>
    <?php
    // GravDept:
    $photoswipeIndex = 0;
    ?>
    <section class="slider regular gallery-section">
        <?php foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail): ?>
            <div class="zoom zoom-img">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $thumbnail->getFile()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($thumbnail->getLabel()); ?>">
            </div>
            <?php $photoswipeIndex++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (count($thumbnails) > 0): ?>
    <?php
    $photoswipeIndex = 0;
    ?>
    <ul class="slider-nav" style="width: 25%;">
        <?php foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail): ?>
            <li style="float: left;display: inline-block;">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $thumbnail->getFile()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($thumbnail->getLabel()); ?>"/>
            </li>
            <?php $photoswipeIndex++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have edited my Question. regular gallery-section refers the slider for thumbnail image and slider-nav section refers small thumbnail image slider.
Value of $thumbnails is 5.

Comment: It's probably due to an **infinite loop**. However, I can't be sure, as you've provided no code. In order for us to help, you will need to actually **show** us your code; we can't help you without it ;) Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have edited my question with php code.